# How to repeat same datetime data for different interval

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I have this dataset

```
                     Value1      Value2
2000-01-01 12:00:00     1        2

2000-01-02 12:00:00     3        4  
2000-01-03 12:00:00     5        6
```

I want to repeat the same data but at 4 different time intervals for example

```
                     Value1      Value2
2000-01-01 00:00:00   1            2

2000-01-01 06:00:00   1            2    
2000-01-01 12:00:00   1            2    
2000-01-01 18:00:00   1            2    

2000-01-02 00:00:00      3          4

2000-01-02 06:00:00      3          4

2000-01-02 12:00:00      3          4


2000-01-02 18:00:00      3          4
```

and so on.

Comment: `df.resample('6H').ffill()` you can resample the data with 6hours followed by forward fill for null values

Answer (score 0):

- your dates are contiguous,  this solution will also work for none contiguous dates
- generate a series that are the expanded times,  then outer join

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""                     Value1      Value2
2000-01-01 12:00:00     1        2
2000-01-02 12:00:00     3        4  
2000-01-03 12:00:00     5        6"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index))

df = df.join(
    pd.Series(df.index, index=df.index)
    .rename("expanded")
    .dt.date.apply(lambda d: pd.date_range(d, freq="6H", periods=4))
    .explode()
).set_index("expanded")

df
```

| expanded | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 2 |
| 2000-01-01 06:00:00 | 1 | 2 |
| 2000-01-01 12:00:00 | 1 | 2 |
| 2000-01-01 18:00:00 | 1 | 2 |
| 2000-01-02 00:00:00 | 3 | 4 |
| 2000-01-02 06:00:00 | 3 | 4 |
| 2000-01-02 12:00:00 | 3 | 4 |
| 2000-01-02 18:00:00 | 3 | 4 |
| 2000-01-03 00:00:00 | 5 | 6 |
| 2000-01-03 06:00:00 | 5 | 6 |
| 2000-01-03 12:00:00 | 5 | 6 |
| 2000-01-03 18:00:00 | 5 | 6 |